# udev rules don't appear to be working

Tags: arch-linux, usb, udev

I'm running Arch Linux on my server, and I need to let users of the group **usb** access my weather station.

Here's my rule:
/etc/udev/rules.d/usb-70.rules

```
SYSFS {idVendor} == "1941", SYSFS {idProduct} == "8021", MODE = "0666", GROUP = "usb"
```

Users in the usb group still can't see the device (permission denied). The Vendor and Product ID is confirmed correct, and I've rebooted 50 million times to no avail. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Could a later rule be overriding yours? Is this the complete file listing? What other files come later (in lexicographic order) in `/etc/udev/rules.d`?

Comment: Run `udevadm monitor` to watch `udev` events, and then re-plug your USB device (or use `udevadm trigger`).

Comment: Or use `udevadm test /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2:3-4` where the path locates your USB device (this path will depend on where it's plugged in, but that's only for debugging).

Answer (score 2):

Can you add `SUBSYSTEM=="usb"` to the beginning of that rule?

If the version of udev is old enough (no idea what Arch uses, sorry), it might be `BUS=="usb"`, instead.

What are the permissions on the device?

If none of that helps, can you show us the `udevadm info` output for that device?

Answer (score 2):

SYSFS has been replaced by ATTR, at least in the udev version used by Debian. So try this instead of your rule:

```
ATTR {idVendor} == "1941", ATTR {idProduct} == "8021", \
  MODE = "0666", GROUP = "usb"
```

Comment: I fail to see the difference